# Build an "IF/ELSE IF/ELSE" loop in Pine Script and avoid "Mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Tags: pine-script

As a total beginner in Pine Script, I am trying to iteratively build an array based on the value of two variables. I come from Python experience and, looking at Pine Script documentation, I would expect it to be something similar to what I have tried below.
However, I receive a "Mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'" error for the first "else if" statement. Does anyone have a second to find what is probably a trivial issue to a more experienced Pine Script coder? Thank you

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
//@version=5
indicator('Automated Label')
past_return = input(10, "Old return - Consider return x old candles")
more_recent_return = input(5, "Recent return - Consider return x old candles")

Rtd1 = (close - close[past_return]) / close[past_return]
Rtd2 = (close - close[more_recent_return]) / close[more_recent_return]

pre_label = array.new_float(0)


if Rtd1 > 0 and Rtd2 > 0
    if Rtd1 > Rtd2
        array.push(pre_label, value=4)
    else
        array.push(pre_label, value=3)
else if Rtd2 > 0
    array.push(pre_label, value=1)
else if Rtd1 < 0 and Rtd2 < 0)
    if Rtd1 < Rtd2
        array.push(pre_label, -4)
    else
        array.push(pre_label, -3)
else if Rtd2 < 0
    array.push(pre_label, -1)
else
    array.push(pre_label,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is misleading, possibly because it cannot parse the whole if-block properly. The actual cause is an unpared `)` in the second `else if` block:

```
else if Rtd1 < 0 and Rtd2 < 0)
```

Delete the last bracket and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I was going crazy looking for more complex answers; I can't believe I oversaw that. The error is certainly misleading, hopefully a future version will have a better error-giving system. Thanks again!